# Center text in a horizontal navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I want my text in the middle of the navigation bar. I tried vertical-align:center or middle but that didn't work.

Here is what I have:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 60px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you want the text to align center vertically or horizontally? or you just want it to be in the middle of the `parent` the u can use `line-height`

Answer (score 2):

Set the `line-height` property equal to the `height` of your element :

```
li a {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: If it did it for you please mark as answer the first answer

Answer (score 1):

In order to vertically centralise the text, you need set a `line-height` equal to the height of the element. In this case, it's 60px:

```
li a {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css3_flexbox.asp) (`display: flex`) to center the text. It's more flexible than `line-height` (`height` can be a percentage) and has good browser support. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 60px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i'd recommend this answer, though `line-height` does the same but still `flex` is better

Comment: I would disagree, it is a very neat solution but has less support in older browsers (especially IE9-) as also said by @Justin Taddei himself

Comment: @Evochrome IE9 has a global usage of 0.27% according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). Worth noting, but not really a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #333;
}
.nav li{
    display:inline;
}
.nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 22px;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey Matt, welcome to SO. It's great that you're trying to help people fix their code. However, when you do so, it is greatly appreciated to explain (could be short) what you exactly did. Keep up the good work and happy coding :)

Comment: The "magic" in the code is text-align: center; along with display: inline-block; that puts the content in the center of the div as requested. There is also the ability to use display:inline-block; with margin: 0 auto; as well.